# What does an Impedance of a transformer mean?

Tags: transformer, impedance, inductance

If Impedance is given as following,

Center Frequency : 455KHz

Pri = 60KOhm

Sec = 600Ohm
Inductance = 680uH

Tuning Capacitane = 180pF + 5pF(ext.)

What do they mean?

1. Do they mean impedance at 455KHz?
2. Then, Shouldn't primary impedance depend on the inductance? which is 680uH which gives 2*pi*455KHz * 680uH = 2KOhm?

[Datasheets for transformer](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/449/XC-600131-205883.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inductance of 680 µH would refer to the "Pri" (primary) winding. This inductance resonates at 455 kHz with 180 pF in parallel. The "Sec" (secondary) winding of 600 Ohms would be an untuned winding.

Turns ratio is the square root of impedance ratio:

$$
\sqrt{60000 \over 600} = 10:1
$$

Yes, these impedances are at 455 kHz, and with this design impedance, you get a loaded Q suitable for AM radio use. A primary impedance of 60 kOhms would yield a bandwidth of about 14 kHz. Loaded Q would be about 30.

The unloaded Q of the primary winding is considerably higher than 30. Normally, a transistor collector would drive this winding, and would present about 60 kOhm impedance (1/hoe) to the primary winding. I1, combined with R1 simulate the output port of that driving transistor. The secondary winding would drive the base of the next transistor, and present a reasonable match to its base-to-emitter input impedance. I would guess that you'll find a tiny 180 pF polystyrene capacitor buried in the plastic base. However, some I.F. transformers expect you to supply this capacitor externally.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJxwnq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Note that the transformer may require adjustment (using a plastic "screwdriver" in the adjustment slot in the core to achieve these precise values. The core is fragile and metal tools can fracture it (as well as disturb the inductance when close to the core!)

Answer (score 0):

The impedance of a transformer means the designed impedance of the target circuit to be interfaced with. So, in case of the example, the transformer is designed to interface a source with an impedance of 60 k to a load with an impedance of 600 ohms or vice versa.

Note that the IF transformer is a tuned circuit with LC resonance. Therefore the circuit impedance is not equal to the simple reactance of the inductor.

Also note that the primary winding is tapped (refer to the datasheet) and the impedance transformation is from the primary's pin 1 and pin 2 to the secondary, where the turns ratio is 10:1. Usually the pin 3 is left unconnected.

Comment: This is a good comment but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Ok, I have clarified further.